# Яндекс карты и выпадающее меню из массива JSON

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, geojson

Делается по образцам из песочницы по добавлению массива точек и созданию собственного выпадающего меню. На данный момент точки по карте расставляются, а вот как обращаться с массивом JSON и из него дёргать нужную информацию пока так и не понял. На данный момент дошёл до такого, но это не работает

```
$.getJSON('geojson.json').done(function (json){
for (var y = 0; y < json.features.length; y++) {
  var b = json.features[y]["properties"].address,
  c = json.features[y]["geometry"].coordinates;
  var listBoxItem = new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
         data: {
         content: b,
         center: c
         }
  })
 }
});
```

Буду благодарен за помощь, или хотя бы за подсказку, где подсмотреть и что можно адаптировать под мою цель. При необходимости - [демка](https://jsfiddle.net/nt6jgpo9/13/), но без JSON она может быть бесполезной. Кроссдоменные запросы на демку делать не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что функция, передаваемая в качестве аргумента `$.getJSON('geojson.json').done()` выполняется асинхронно. К этому моменту ваш `listBox` будет создан с пустым списком и его нужно будет наполнять (`listBox.add()`). Кроме того ваш `listBox` создается динамически и момент инициализации выпадающих спиской библиотекой *materialize* уже прошел, потребуется инициализировать его отдельно после наполнения.

С учетом вышесказаного функция наполнения списка должна выглядеть так:

```
a = $.getJSON('geojson.json').done(function (json) {
    for (var y = 0; y < json.features.length; y++) {
        var b = json.features[y]["properties"].address,
            c = json.features[y]["geometry"].coordinates;
            var listBoxItem = new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
            data: {
                content: b,
                center: c
            }
        });
        // Добавляем пункт в список
        listBox.add(listBoxItem);
    }
    // Инициализируем список
    $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({});
});
```

Кроме того необходимо определение переменной `listBox` перенести выше этого участка кода и сделать ваш `geojson.json` валидным (уберите первую строку оттуда)

Comment: неожиданно подробное разъяснение. А можно пару уточнений?
Ввиду того, что я мало знаю о работе JSON, хотел бы уточнить, можно ли избежать убирания первой строки из JSON файла, так как он позже используется в инициализации точек на карте, или же это ни на что не повлияет?

Comment: @spirit-infernal Я имел ввиду строку вида `header(...` Если JSON будет невалидным, он не загрузится (JSON - это слегка более формализованная форма JavaScript-записи массивов и объектов - если по-простому. О его работе, по сути, знать-то нечего)

Comment: geojson.json не имеет такой строки в составе, я его делал через сервис для создания меток из xls файла с названиями точек. вот его заголовок:
   {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates": ["82.763045", "52.49635"]
  },
  "properties": {
   "id": "0",
   "address": "\u0410\u043b\u0435\u0439\u0441\u043a, \u0443\u043b. \u041e\u043b\u0435\u0448\u043a\u043e, 40\u0415",
   "index": "0"
  },
   "options": {
    "preset": "islands#violetGovernmentIcon"
   }
 },
стоит ли что-то убирать?

Comment: я своими силами пытался также исследовать момент о том, почему на данный момент в качестве содержимого выводится нечто подобное:
l {state: h, data: h, options: Object, events: s, _itemImplementation: n…}
_enabled
:
true
_itemImplementation
:
n
_layout
:
null
_layoutDeferred
:
null
_selected
:
undefined
data
:
h
eventProxy
:
l
events
:
s
options
:
Object
state
:
h
__proto__
:
i
насколько я понял, это и есть объект конструктора карт. Но вот что с ним делать пока не удалось понять. Пробую ваш метод

Comment: @spirit-infernal Из приведенного куска убирать ничего не нужно. В предоставленном jsfiddle был geojson.json c первой строкой, начинающейся с `header(`

Comment: да, простите. я ненамеренно вас и себя запутал. Метод сработал, но пункты выпадающего меню не выводятся, хотя и наполнены данными. возможно это проблема самого материалайза уже? с ней справлюсь.

Comment: @spirit-infernal Я решение проверял локально. Все работало. Где сейчас проблема не смогу сказать, не имея доступа к рабочей странице. Посмотрите в консоли браузера - ошибок нету?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46119/discussion-between-spirit-infernal-and-tutankhamun).